# Sending email with a Ruby script - 501 5.5.4 Invalid Address

Tags: ruby, email, smtp

I'm trying to send email with a Ruby script, but my proof of concept isn't working.  I can telnet to the mail server and send mail that way, but this script causes the mail server to raise an error: `501 5.5.4 Invalid Address`

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'net/smtp'

def send_email(to, subject = "", body = "")
    from = "my@email.com"
    body= "From: #{from}\r\nTo: #{to}\r\nSubject: #{subject}\r\n\r\n#{body}\r\n"

    Net::SMTP.start('192.168.10.213', 25, '192.168.0.218') do |smtp|
        smtp.send_message body, from, to
    end
end

send_email "my@email.com", "test", "blah blah blah"
```

In my actual script, `my@email.com` is a valid email. `192.168.10.213` is the mail server and `192.168.0.218` is my local ip.  Note that I'm running windows xp, and the mail server is an exchange server.

I don't understand why telnet works with the same values, but this script raises the invalid address error.

Can somebody help me?

**EDIT**: The above code now works fine, I originally left out the commas in the final method call.  I feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you believe it?  I feel like an idiot, I'm just missing commas in the method call...

`send_email "my@email.com", "test", "blah blah blah"`

I'm embarrassed.

Anyway, the above code works great if anyone is interested.  Just don't leave out the commas like I did.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your actual email address does not contain invalid characters. For example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200486/why-do-i-get-5-5-4-invalid-address-error).

Comment: Thanks, but both my machine name and my email address are perfectly valid, no odd characters, no leading or trailing white-space or dots.  My machine name does have a dash in it though... it's a hassle to change my computer name, as I'm in a corporate network.  Could the dash be the problem?  Remember, telnet works!

Comment: Dash should be fine, though underscore isn't valid for domains. You might need to look at the SMTP traffic to see what the server is actually seeing - it may not be what you think it's seeing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [Action Mailer](http://am.rubyonrails.org/) for sending mails with Ruby. See a snippet [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6621).

Comment: I'd rather use Net::SMTP ... I don't need all that jazz.  Using anything that's not in the ruby core is my last resort (ie Action Mailer or TMail or similar)

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in your code. A malicious user could insert more headers into your email by using newlines in the subject.

Comment: Good catch. This code was only used as a locally run script for a one time use batch job, so I didn't consider that kind of security. It's still a good point though for anyone else who may want to use this code. Thanks.