# Ruby Email Client Recommendation

Tags: ruby, email, encoding, mime

We are writing an email web client in Ruby to handle (potentially international) emails.  I am looking for a high-level email library that supports retrieving emails, parsing email raw, decoding MIME, and converting input into `UTF-8`.  Is there a library that you can recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try any of these:

- [TMail](http://tmail.rubyforge.org/)
- [Action Mailer](http://am.rubyonrails.org/)
- [RubyMail](http://www.rfc20.org/rubymail/)

If you want to re-invent the wheel, there is the native [Net::SMTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/classes/Net/SMTP.html) class.  In [another StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200882/sending-email-with-a-ruby-script-501-5-5-4-invalid-address), there is a good proof of concept of this.

Comment: I looked into TMail, but I cannot find how to decide `MIME` subjects.

Comment: [TMail](http://tmail.rubyforge.org/) was replaced by [mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail) as described on the [TMail site](http://tmail.rubyforge.org/). [mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail) is now the default library for ActionMailer in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite library for handling mail is [MailFactory](http://rubyforge.org/projects/mailfactory)

Ruby comes with net/imap and net/pop to handle retrieving mail.

Answer (score 0):

Check out also:

- https://github.com/wmorgan/heliotrope
- http://github.com/wmorgan/turnsole

Very promising "mutt"-like e-mail client written in Ruby!